# test string against multiple regexes in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test a given string against 20 or so regular expressions. What's a clean way to do this in Javascript? I'm more concerned about clean code and readability than efficiency (but I don't want it to be super slow either).

Right now I have:

```
if (href.indexOf('apple.com') > -1 ||
    href.indexOf('google.com') > -1 ||
    href.indexOf('yahoo.com') > -1 ||
    href.indexOf('facebook.com') > -1) {
    performDarkMagic()
}
```

But it's going to start looking kind of messy as that list grows. 
Maybe I could just create an array of regular expressions and execute something like _.any() and apply regex.test on each?

Edit: the strings/regexes to match may become more complicated, I just used simple URLs to make the example readable.

Answer (score 9):

Use the test function for regular expressions.

More information on regular expressions here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

```
var re = /((google)|(facebook)|(yahoo)|(apple))\.com/;
re.test( str ); // returns true or false;
```

Test cases.

Live Demo Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rkzXP/1/

```
    var func = function( str ){
        var re = /((google)|(facebook)|(yahoo)|(apple))\.com/;
        return re.test( str );
    };
    test("test for valid values", function() {
        equal( func("google.com"), true);
        equal( func("facebook.com"), true);
        equal( func("apple.com"), true);
    });
    test("test for invalid values", function() {
        equal( func("googl.com"), false);
        equal( func("faceook.com"), false);
        equal( func("apple"), false);
    });
```

So you can rewrite your code as the following.

```
var re = /((google)|(facebook)|(yahoo)|(apple))\.com/;
if( re.test(str) ){
    performDarkMagic()
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry it's for qunit. But it's not needed. Let me take it out.

Answer (score 4):

```
var patterns = ['apple.com', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'facebook.com', ...]
var callFunc = false;

patterns.forEach(function(item){
   if(href.indexOf(item) > -1){
       callFunc = true;
       break;
   }
});

if(callFunc) {
   performDarkMagic();
}
```

Comment: `forEach` ftw +1 /me waits for the people to caution against it working not working in IE.. le sigh.

Comment: @Bergi why would you downvote that? Its a much more elegant solution than the one you provided.. which doesn't look much different from the op's.

Comment: @Loktar: Because the OP needs some()!

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (like in my answer). Read carefully what the OP's expression means. Your code does something quite different.

Comment: Ah I see now. @Bergi you should of put that originally :P. Your func will keep going @hunterMcMillen whereas `some` will stop and not continue execution. Touche @Bergi.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, building an array and using [`.any()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-21) or [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is just fine, especially when there will be more than 4 values:

```
if (["apple","google","yahoo","facebook"].some(host => href.includes(`${host}.com`)) {
    performLightMagic();
}
```

Yet I can't see regexes there, there are just strings; so you could simplify using [`regex.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to:

```
if (/apple\.com|google\.com|yahoo\.com|facebook\.com/.test(href)) { performLightMagic(); }
```

or even

```
if (/(apple|google|yahoo|facebook)\.com/.test(href)) { performLightMagic(); }
```

Comment: This would get out of hand and ugly very quickly the larger the list gets.

Comment: Hm, it's much more shorthand than array notation. Of course everything depends on reusability of that object...

Comment: Yeah in his question though he said he has to test against 20 or so. IMO an array is the cleaner looking method.

Comment: I never said it would not :-) And for independent regexes, as he mentioned, the array will be easier to build.

Answer (score 2):

You could put each one in array then looping over each.

Answer (score -1):

How I would do it: factor it out into a function. Put each regex in an array, loop over them and return true the first time indexOf > -1. If you reach the end of the loop return false.

Answer (score -2):

Loop through a regex array and then do:

```
result=result AND (result_of_regex);

next;
```

after the loop return result